# The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities with skip

Tags: c#, linq

I have error The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

```
var result = context.Users.Include("Roles")
                          .OrderBy(x => x.UserID)
                          .Where(x => !userIsAdmin(x))
                          .Skip(skip)
                          .Take(take)
                          .ToList();

private readonly Func<User, bool> userIsAdmin = u => u.Roles.Any(y => y.Name.Equals(AdminRoleName));
```

Where I writing wrong?

Comment: @Amit here: `.Where(x => !userIsAdmin(x))`. `Where` builds an expression out of its lambda parameter; in this expression userIsAdmin is a `Func`, thus, it's translated into [Expression.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355170(v=vs.110).aspx) And EntityFramework does not support `Expression.Invoke` because it has no idea how to translate that to SQL.

Comment: take a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx

Answer (score 3):

LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities both work on `Expression`, not on `Func` (like LINQ to Objects does), so you have to declare your `userIsAdmin` as `Expression<Func<User, bool>>`:

```
private readonly Expression<Func<User, bool>> userIsAdmin = u => u.Roles.Any(y => y.Name.Equals(AdminRoleName));
```

You should also consider changing the expression to:

```
private readonly Expression<Func<User, bool>> userIsAdmin = u => u.Roles.Select(y => y.Name).Contains(AdminRoleName));
```

It should be translated into `IN` statement within generated SQL query.

Comment: I have new error- The name 'userIsAdmin' does not exist in the current context

Comment: that's not going to work at all. (x => !userIsAdmin(x)) will bug out as you cannot call an expression like that it's not a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

MarcinJuraszek is on the right track. You can change your predicate to:

```
private readonly Expression<Func<User, bool>> userIsNotAdmin = u => !u.Roles.Any(y => y.Name.Equals(AdminRoleName));
```

Note that this is an inversion of what you have.

And then you should be able to call it like this:

```
var result = context.Users.Include("Roles")
                      .OrderBy(x => x.UserID)
                      .Where(userIsNotAdmin)
                      .Skip(skip)
                      .Take(take)
                      .ToList();
```